# Passing string list to F# asp.Net api

Tags: asp.net, f#, c#-to-f#

I actually solved my problem before posting, but I wonder if there are any better solutions?
Also if there is somewhere where there is a way to use list as-is?

---

I am writing a simple get endpoint if F# which needs to accept a list of strings as an argument.

I take that list as the input to a query that runs as expected, I am not worried about that part.

The problem I am facing is as follows (minimal implmenetation):

When I define the endpoint as:

```
    
[<HttpGet>]
member _.Get() =
  processStrings [ "test"; "test2" ]
```

it returns as expected.

When I change it to:

```
[<HttpGet>]
member _.Get([<FromQuery>] stringList: string list) = processStrings stringList
```

I get an error:

InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[[System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]]'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'stringList' parameter a non-null default value.

Which doesn't make much sense to me, as I am using a list of strings, which in C# at least defaults to an empty list.

So I assume this comes down to how C# and F# interpret these signatures, but I am not sure how to resolve it.

I tried this signature and received the same error as above....

```
member _.Get( [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue([||]); FromQuery>] stringList: string list) = processStrings stringList
```

In the end using the following did solve the problem.

```
member _.Get( [<Optional; DefaultParameterValue([||]); FromQuery>] stringList: string seq) = processStrings stringList
```

I assume it was solved because seq is just IEnumerable, and then presumable list isn't just List from C# (mutable vs immutable). But is there a way to use an F# list in [FromQuery] parameters? Would [FromBody] have just worked? (No is the tested answer) Is there a way to add a type provider for an endpoint like this?

Is there something else I am missing here? Mine works now, but I am curious to the implications of the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I would assume that ASP.NET does not support F# lists as arguments. I would guess that taking the argument as an array would be much more likely to work:

```
[<HttpGet>]
member _.Get([<FromQuery>] stringList: string[]) = 
  processStrings (List.ofArray stringList)
```

Comment: I just checked, because it is bothering, and string[] does work.

So what really what I am looking for is what is the rule here?

I am working form memory but I think Array is also based on the C# implementation and is mutable, instead of mutable... Unless I remembering incorrectly.

So if ASP.NET doesn't support F# lists, it is probably safe to assume it is not going to accept any F# native types, and only those shared with C#. I'll have to play a bit more, but   this could be a bit of a bummer (though how often it will be a problem remains to be seen),

Comment: @FlippievanDyk I'm not an expert on this, but I think F# records would work fine (they compile to normal classes). The issue with lists is that they are compiled as immutable linked list classes, so they might work if your JSON is something like `{ Value:12, Cons:{ Value:13, Cons: null } }`, but you obviously don't want to represent anything in this way...

Comment: Thank you very much, as you say, I think it is likely the F# lists that are the problem. Using Arrays isn't such a hardship